# angular $index numbering with condition in ng-repeat & ui-sortable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-filters

I'm trying to achieve customized numbering while listing all items in an array.

All items in array are rendered using ng-repeat & ui.sortable.

**Numbering must be done in such a way that, for an array item "statement", count should not be increased & displayed.**
(*Else I may be used $index instead of an external count.*)

**For any other array item, count should be increased & displayed.**

The solution that got me the the closest result was the one where I passed $index into a filter function written in the controller.

like in HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="question in questions">

<div class="no"> {{ filterIndex(question.question, $index) }} </div>
<div>{{question.question}}</div>

</li>
```

in controller:

```
    var filterValue = 0;

    $scope.filterIndex = function (value, count) {

        if (count === 0) {
            filterValue = 0;
        }

        if (value !== 'statementText') {
            filterValue = filterValue + 1;
            return filterValue;
        }
        else {
            return '"';
        }

    };
```

Even it was working without any errors, **the count returned from function is not get updated** like we get with $index when we update the order using ui-sortable.

see it here: [js-fiddle using filter function](http://jsfiddle.net/PwQUC/61/)

means, once it rendered **(4)** in **<[ (4) fourth question ]>** will remain same even if we moved it to top or bottom by dragging.

I tried different ways and almost everything ended up on **'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.'**.
Real scenario is a little bit complex as it contains nested ng-repeats and similar counting with digits and numbers alternatively in child loops.

Here is link to start fresh:
[js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwQUC/60/)

Comment: [answer here](http://jsfiddle.net/PwQUC/63/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject this to your controller, it will listen for array changes, and update the indexes:

```
  var update = function(){
      var currentCount = 0;
      var questions = $scope.questions;
      for(var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++){
          if(questions[j].question != null){
              if(questions[j].question.indexOf("statement") < 0){
                  questions[j].calculatedIndex = ++currentCount;
              }
          }
      }
  };

  $scope.$watchCollection('questions', function(){
    update();      
  });

  update();
```

probably needs a bit fine-tuning as I didn't concentrate on your question completely. In the ng-repeat, you now have access to calculatedIndex. It will be "NULL" for statement items, you can use ng-show for that.

Comment: Oh! that was simple!! Thanks for the exact solution! I should stop making things complicated!!

Answer (score 0):

just try to add extra option:

```
ng-init='question.index = $index+1'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ny279bry/

Comment: Could you please have a look at the highlighted areas in the question., I think we are on different poles.